# 31.65% of SQL Queries are SET NAME. Is it Necessary?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Looking at the database query statistics, I can see that 31.65% of the SQL Queries are SET option. I am using Zend Framework 2 with PDO extension. I do not use SET option anywhere other than in my global.php:

```
'db' => array(
            'driver' => 'Pdo',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=db;',
            'driver_options' => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
            ),
        ),
```

The collation of the database (MariaDB) is utf8_general_ci.
Is this needed? Can I remove this driver option? Cannot this be defined in the database once and for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this option to set encoding of each db connection just after the connection has been created. Collation of database is quite another option that does not effect the encoding of current connection. 
You can miss this option if you have a guarantee that mysql server is set by default to work with utf8 connections and its setting will not change without your participation (but in this case you may have a problem with portability of your application).
Fortunately queries like SET NAMES ... is quite fast.

Comment: How do I know if the mysql server is set by default to work with utf8 connections?

Comment: _A SET NAMES 'charset_name' statement is equivalent to these three statements:_
`SET character_set_client = charset_name;
SET character_set_results = charset_name;
SET character_set_connection = charset_name;`
[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html]

You should open mysql config file on your server (usually /etc/my.cnf), find section [mysqld] and finally make sure that these options is set to UTF-8.

Comment: Also you should set to utf8 client-encoding in `[client]` section.
Usually you should have setting like the following in you conf.file:
`[mysqld]
init_connect=‘SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci’
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci

[client]
default-character-set = utf8`

Comment: This has been thorough. Thanks!